# Dell R7525 Subiquity install fails

Tags: dell, subiquity

We have a Dell R7525 with NVIDIA GPU and NVMe drive. When we autoinstall ubuntu-20.04.5-live-server, the install completes. However when the server reboots after the install it just hangs on a black screen.

### Any suggestions on how to fix, or even how to debug the problem, would be appreciated.

Added: we're not even getting the SSH port open, so it's more than just a blank console screen. The usual CTRL-ALT F1, F3 ... also doesn't work.

Comment: Did you install nVidia driver as part of install or the restricted drivers? Can you boot to grub menu. If only Ubuntu, you need to press escape just after Dell logo but before grub menu normally appears to get the menu. Then boot recovery mode? You can install nVidia driver from there, if you can boot to terminal with Internet on.

Comment: No, we usually install the nvidia drivers as a post install step. This works for our other Dell servers (e.g. R750's)